# Restcomm - It is Possible change the Database configuration

Tags: jboss7.x, telecommunication, restcomm

This is my first steps with **Restcomm**,

I got install the restcomm (jboss version), on the first time I got to hear the *welcome message*, and I got to access to the admin page.

Then, I tried to restart the jboss, I saw some errors. And I tried to change the dabase in the ibatis.conf from *hsql* to *postgresql*.

My question is:

If is possible to change the database (users,roles and rules) and where I can find the instructions for do this.

And I have another question

```
    <dataSource type="POOLED">
        <property name="driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file://${data}/restcomm;ifexists=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;shutdown=true"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
      </dataSource>
```

Where the *restcomm* save the data of the hsql, because I deleted all, install again and then my problem continues.

Answer (score 3):

The following link shows how to configure a different database on Restcomm (MariaDB).

http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-install-and-configure-restcomm-to-use-mariadb/

You will also need the driver to configure the PostgreSQL DB.